# How do SEL and @selector work?

Tags: objective-c

```
typedef struct objc_selector  *SEL;
```

In the code above, `SEL` type in objective-c is a pointer to `struct objc_selector`. So, if I make a `SEL` variable like:

```
SEL aSel = @selector(instanceMethod) //Like this
```

What happens? What did `@selector` do to the instance method, `instanceMethod`?

Comment: Conceptually, `@selector(...)` is to `SEL` as `"..."` is to `const char *` or `@"..."` is to `NSString *`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@selector` directive simply takes a method name and returns an appropriate identifier for that method. This identifier is used to determine which method to invoke when the selector does eventually get performed:

```
SEL aSel = @selector(instanceMethod);

// Calls -instanceMethod on someObject
[someObject performSelector:aSel];
```

You can find details in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html).

Comment: One more thing, if `aSel` is a struct pointer, what exactly is in the struct?

Comment: @MiguelC: See hamstergene's answer that was just posted.

Answer (score 25):

Internally, `SEL` is equivalent to `const char[]` that simply holds method name. In fact, they are just C strings:

```
(lldb) p _cmd
(SEL) $0 = "windowDidLoad"
(lldb) p (const char*) _cmd
(const char *) $1 = 0x91ae954e "windowDidLoad"
```

The important exception is that these pointers are globally unique in the process, even across  static modules and dynamic library boundaries, so they are comparable using `==`. Unlike C strings which can not be compared by pointer values (`"instanceMethod" == @selector(instanceMethod)` may and **will** fail), selectors are comparable by pointer value: no matter how selector was created, two `SEL` values for the same selector are always equal.

`@selector(instanceMethod)` syntax creates C string `"instanceMethod"` then passes to Obj-C runtime function which turns it into unique pointer value corresponding to that string. What it basically does is

```
SEL sel = @selector(instanceMethod);
SEL sel = sel_registerName("instanceMethod");
```

P.S. `struct objc_selector` does not exist, it is to make `SEL` values incompatible with C strings, and hide selector implementation details from you. For even better understanding, you may read in [Obj-C runtime source code for selectors](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-sel.mm) what those `sel_getName` and `sel_registerName` actually do.

Comment: To emphasize that last point;  **do not treat SEL as compatible with `char*`.**.   That is an implementation detail that *might* change in the future (it probably won't for compatibility reasons... but it could).

Comment: This is great information, concisely stated, and not covered in the answers to the other question that this question supposedly duplicates. Thanks!