# Using a NSNotification as an if argument

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Just wondering if there is a way to use a NSNotification observer as an if statement argument, or to have a block of code in your selector section

EG

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector( { SOME NEW CODE GOES HERE! ) name:@"addressTypeChanged" object:nil];

OR

if ([[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(self) name:@"addressTypeChanged" object:nil]) {

//some code//
}
```

Comment: You can pass a block which has been copied onto the heap as an argument for the target, (and use the `-invoke` selector) but that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To your first line:** No, there's no way to place a block within `@selector()`. It might be worth taking a look around at what @selector is and how it works. [Here's one particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322264/how-do-sel-and-selector-work) that might put you on the right track.

**To your second line:** The `addObserver:selector:...` method has a `void` return type and would always equate to `NO` inside an `if` statement.

What you might be looking for is the `NSNotificationCenter` block based API:

```
- (id)addObserverForName:(NSString *)name 
                  object:(id)obj 
                   queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue 
              usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification *))block
```

The `block` parameter will be called when the notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"addressTypeChanged"
                                                  object:object
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
                                                  /*
                                                    here you can call another methos
                                                   */
                                              }];
```