# What is the objc_selector implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, selector, objective-c-runtime

I've found that the `SEL` type has the next definition:

```
typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;
```

But I can't find how is `objc_selector` implemented.

Okay, if we have the next code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  SEL mySelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"mySelector");
  return 0;
}
```

, then `mySelector` is just a pointer. Following the address which it contains, we see the C-string, which *can be* presented like:

```
const char* mySelector = "mySelector";
```

But `objc_selector` is not a C-string, it is structure and it can contain something else. So I want to know how `objc_selector` structure is implemented.

Comment: This is a more detailed answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19322677/1016102

Comment: @DanielBocksteger wow thank you so much man! I have no idea why i didn't find this answer before. Please post this link to answer, I want to choose your answer as correct. It really saved my time!

Comment: SEL is closed structure. It content shouldn't bother you.

Comment: This is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19322677/1016102 which Alexander searched for... but dehlens is correct and good too :-)

Comment: `objc_selector` has no implementation, cause the c/c++ compiler allow undefined struct, plz refer `https://gist.github.com/Jichao/f663400a0a56011171291bbac9aa372b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you:

> Now this one is fun and interesting. SEL is the type of a *"selector"* which identifies the name of a method (not the implementation). So, for example, the methods `-[Foo count]` and `-[Bar count]` both share a selector, namely the selector `"count"`. A SEL is a pointer to a struct `objc_selector`, but what the heck is an `objc_selector`? Well, it's defined differently depending on if you're using the GNU Objective-C runtime, or the NeXT Objective-C Runtime (like Mac OS X). Well, it ends up that Mac OS X maps SELs to simple `C strings`. For example, if we define a Foo class with a `- (int)blah method`, the code `NSLog(@"SEL = %s", @selector(blah));` would output `SEL = blah.`

Taken from: [here](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.de/2006/02/nil-and-nil.html)

Comment: Also you should not assume that the implementation stays the same. Only because it's a C string right now doesn't mean it's one in the future.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the implementation is the same on 32 and 64 bit MacOS X, on different versions of MacOS X, and on 32 and 64 bit iOS, including again different versions of iOS. Just because it's a C string right now in one of several implementations of Objective-C doesn't mean it's the same on all.

Comment: Unfortunately the blog link is now dead, "Sorry, the blog at unixjunkie.blogspot.com has been removed. This address is not available for new blogs."